# How do I keep my mobile AIR application on landscape mode?

Tags: ios, apache-flex, mobile, air, adobe

I can't seem to find any way to force it to go landscape mode all the time. When I go to MyApp-app.xml and edit the `<aspectRatio></aspectRatio>` tags to **landscape**, only the main view is landscaped. If I navigate to the second view, it turns back to **portrait**. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

You can set it on Properties of the Document. Go to File>Publish Settings> Click on Configuration Player ("Air for Android", "Air for iOS", "Flash Player 11", etc).
Now, mark the "Auto Orietation".

Like this:

[image]

Now, save, and Test.

Answer (score 0):

Devices could be a huge factor in this.  What device are you having the problem on?

That said, in addition to setting aspectRatio to landscape I would try to set autoOrients to false:

```
    <!-- The initial aspect ratio of the app when launched (either "portrait" or "landscape"). Optional. Mobile only. Default is the natural orientation of the device -->
    <aspectRatio>landscape</aspectRatio>

    <!-- Whether the app will begin auto-orienting on launch. Optional. Mobile only. Default false -->
    <autoOrients>false</autoOrients>
```

Comment: I have set tboth aspectRatio and autoOrients correctly already. But if I move to the next view, it reverts back to being portrait. I am aiming for the iPhone 4 device.

Comment: Okay, I exported the whole thing to FXP which you can download here http://www.mediafire.com/download.php?26a6j1ouo61b7kw .