# Is it necessary to adjust the height and width of the stage manually if I want to force a landscape orientation?

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air

I'm just learning to code for iOS using **Adobe AIR**.  I'm familiar, though not very experienced, with ActionScript 3.

I want my app to remain in landscape no matter how the device is oriented.  I know that to set the orientation for an iOS device, I'd have to set `<autoOrients>false</autoOrients>` and `<aspectRatio>landscape</aspectRatio>`.  However, as I'm using Adobe Flash Professional, I was wondering if I need to change my **stage's height and width** to reflect this change in the actual app.

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried autoOrient and aspects i your code ? if not try it in code and post what are the problems you have faced..

Comment: have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9248030/how-do-i-keep-my-mobile-air-application-on-landscape-mode

Answer (score 0):

No you don't have to, once those settings are set it will be handled automatically. stage.stageHeight and stage.stageWidth should report the correct dimensions when the stage is in landscape mode.

Answer (score 0):

Stage.width and Stage.height are readonly.

To force landscape use app descriptor xml definitions like:

landscape
true